# CheckBox [Inside ListBox ItemTemplate] Checked Event is not triggering

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

This is my `xaml`

```
    <ListBox x:Name="HistoryList"          
                     ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryCollection}" 
                       >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            </DataTemplate>                 
                    <CheckBox x:Name="UpCheckBox"   Height="50" Width="50" >
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpCheckedCommad}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UpCheckBox}"></interactivity:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </CheckBox>                 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate >
    </ListBox >
```

In `ViewModel` I have used `GalasoftMVVM Command Binding`

```
    public ICommand UpCheckedCommad
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand<Object>(x => { PerformUpforTracks(x); }); }
    }

    void PerformUpforTracks(object x)
    {
        //TODO 
    }
```

I used a `CheckBox` inside a `ListBox ItemTemplate`.But am not getting the  `Checked` Event of `CheckBox` in the `ViewModel` .
I wanted to get the Checked Event  from my ViewModel.
Can anyone have any idea to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it By Binding `Command` by this way

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UpCheckedCommad,
          ElementName=HistoryList}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Each instance of your ListBox.ItemTemplate is automatically given "the current item in the collection" as its DataContext.  In your case, that is each individual item in the HistoryCollection.  In your example, the EventTrigger is searching for the "ThumbsUpCheckedCommad" inside your current instance of the HistoryItem.

In order to force the EventTrigger to search in your desired ViewModel, you need to specify the "Source" property of your command binding.  I suggest using the RelativeSource syntax, to search up the tree for the last Control to have your ViewModel as its DataContext.

It would look something like this.

```
{Binding Path=ThumbsUpCheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

Comment: can you tell me the namespace belongs 'x'?

Comment: You've already used the "x" namespace in your code sample.  It's a built-in namespace for the XAML schema.  "AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}" is basically just saying "move up the tree until we find a ListBox, and look inside its DataContext for my Binding."

Comment: thanks dude for your help.  I got the answer. Anyway am not getting Type from 'x'.I dont know why it is.

Comment: Ancestor binding does not find the DataContext of the target type, it only finds the first instance of that type. Furthermore, Ancestor Binding was added to Silverlight 5 and is not available in WP7. Your RelativeSource syntax is also incorrect for Silverlight. The Binding should be formatted like so: {Binding Path=DataContext.ThumbsUpCheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}

Comment: That's a great many points you make, @TriggerPin.  Do you have Edit powers?  Because as far as I can tell, it would me much more constructive if you just made the answer correct with a couple edits!  The essence of the answer is still the same; he's looking for a command binding in the wrong DataContext.