# How to access listboxitem template data when an event of it's item control is fired?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I want to access each listboxitem template control's(image and 4 textblock controls  )data when the button is clicked from the following hierarchy.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstBoxNearbyPlaces" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0"  >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="400" Height="150" Name="btnPlace" Click="btnPlace_Click_1">
                                    <Button.Content>                                            
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                                              
                                            <Image  Name="ImgPlace"  Source="{Binding PlaceIconURL}" Width="50" />
                                            <TextBlock Name="lblPlaceLat" Text="{Binding PlaceLatLocation}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <TextBlock Name="lblPlaceLng" Text="{Binding PlaceLongLocation}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <StackPanel Width="350" >                                                    
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="20"   Text="{Binding PlaceName}" Name="txtAddress" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>                                        
                                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding PlaceVicinity}" Name="txtLocation" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                            <Line MinHeight="5"></Line>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Is it possible to get or read the data of the every control here when the button click event is fired ?

Comment: Use Button `Command Binding` This 
may help you

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773883/checkbox-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-checked-event-is-not-triggering

Answer (score 1):

You can get the binding object in the ListBox_SelectionChanged as the selected item.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ItemModel model= listBox.SelectedItem as ItemModel ;
    }
```

Or In the Buttonclick event you can get it as

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        ItemModel model = button.DataContext as ItemModel;
    }
```

Here model is the object which you have bind to that template.